# Max value of a range defined by the month of the dates in another column

Tags: arrays, date, excel-2010, multiple-columns, lookup

I'd like to find the max value for January from column B.

Column A

28.01.2015

29.01.2015

30.01.2015

31.01.2015

01.02.2015

02.02.2015

Column B

5

2

3

1

4

1

I tried something like this, but did not work. 
=MAX(IF(AND(A:A<=DATE(2015;1;1);A:A>=DATE(2015;1;1));B:B;B:B))

I'd appreciate any kind of hint or help. THX in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have **Dates** in column **A** use the *Array Formula:*

```
=MAX(IF(MONTH(A1:A6)=1,B1:B6))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

For example:

[image]